# Is this convolution not-in-L1?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convolution

Consider $x:\mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}_+$, where $x\not\in\mathcal{L}^1$, i.e.,
$$\int_0^\infty x(s)ds = \infty.$$
Consider the convolution
$$h(t) = \int_0^t e^{-(t-s)}x(s)ds.$$
I am wondering if it is possible that $h\in\mathcal{L}^1$, i.e., $$\int_0^\infty h(s)ds = C < \infty.$$
I guess that yes, but I cannot find an example.

I know that for $x\in\mathcal{L}^1$ it holds $h \in \mathcal{L}^1$ but is the opposite true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the functions under consideration are non-negative, you can do the following computation in $[0,+\infty]$ :
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty h(t) dt &= \int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^t e^{-(t-s)} x(s) d s \right) d t \\
&= \int_0^\infty \left(\int_s^\infty e^{-(t-s)} d t \right) x(s) d s \\
&= \int_0^\infty x(s) d s
\end{align*}

So $x$ is integrable if, and only if, $h$ is.

Comment: Thanks! What changes if we consider $\mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$ signals?

Comment: For $x:\mathbb R_+ \to \mathbb R$, using the triangle equality and following similar computations, we have $\int_0^{+\infty} |h(x)| d s \leqslant \int_0^{+\infty} |x(s)|d s$. Therefore, $h$ is integrable whenever $x$ is. The converse is trickier.

Answer (score 1):

you could rewrite:
$$h(t)=e^{-t}\int_0^t e^sx(s)ds$$
Now consider the conditions which are required for:
$$t\to\infty,h\to0$$

it looks like the integral, and so the integrand, would have to diverge slower than $e^t$, in other words:
$$O\left(e^tx(t)\right)<O(e^t)$$

Basically what this means is that if you want the integral of $h$ to converge, the integral of $x$ must also.